# Haskell data type Counts for State Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, monoids

How can I use the following data type for a Monoid instance of it?

```
data Counts = Counts {
    binds   :: Int,
    returns :: Int,
    gets    :: Int,
    puts    :: Int
} deriving (Eq, Show)
```

E.g. I figured something like:

```
mempty  = Counts { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
(Counts { b, r, g, p }) mappend (Counts { b', r', g', p' })  = Counts { (b + b'), (r + r'), (g + g'), (p + p') }
```

But that gives me a parse error on '0'... Maybe I'm doing it totally wrong and misunderstanding the data type / monoid, but I cannot figure it out. If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: another slight syntax error is mappend - you have to enclose it in these ``` characters (sadly the same SO uses to make inline code-blocks

Comment: @CarstenKönig Aah that's right I totally forgot to do that, thank you

Comment: Separate to the question you asked, but: you very likely want to use strict fields (replace `Int` with `!Int`) to avoid space leaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
Counts 0 0 0 0
```

This works:

```
Counts {binds = 0, returns = 0, gets = 0, puts = 0}
```

This does not work:

```
Counts {0, 0, 0, 0}
```

You either have to put the brackets *and the field names*, or you leave the brackets out completely. One or the other.

Other than that, your approach looks sane. You just have your record syntax messed up.

Comment: Aah figured I'd have the syntax messed up, thank you for helping out!